# Why don't web push notifications on Chrome work when Android is inactive?

Tags: android, google-chrome, service-worker, web-push

I've built web push notifications in my app. My client installs a service worker and allows users to subscribe to web push notifications. When a notification is received, the service worker calls showNotification to display the notification.

This setup works as expected and I am able to see web push notifications appear when an Android device is active. However, when the Android device is inactive for ~5 minutes, push notifications do not appear, even when the device is later unlocked.

The specific conditions that define "active", which allow push notifications to work as expected are:

1. Phone is unlocked
2. Phone's display has timed out or phone is locked for less than ~5 minutes
3. Phone is locked for any amount of time, but connected by wire to laptop for debugging

In the service worker push event listener, I've added debug statements which indicate that the "push" event is not being triggered when the phone is in an inactive state. I've tested the Facebook Messenger web app on my Android device, and am noticing that Messenger web push notifications also do not render when the phone is inactive, however the missed notifications  appear as soon as the device is unlocked and active again. For my app, the missed notifications are lost entirely.

**Has anyone faced a similar issue or have any theories for why this may be happening?**
Similar (but unanswered) stack overflow question: [Push Notifications not working when Android inactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71405598/push-notifications-not-working-when-android-inactive?newreg=b85a36811d5d46309a6259e57bbe2fe4)